# Inserting Array values from jQuery into PHP

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, html, mysql

I am using PHP, MySql, jQuery.
I have a html table. I want to get the contents of the html table, and store it in mysql db.

I have taken the contents of the html table in an array using jquery.
This is my jquery code.

```
var myTableArray = [];
$("#my_tbe tr").each(function() {
    var arrayOfThisRow = [];
    var tableData = $(this).find('td');
    if (tableData.length > 0) {
        tableData.each(function() { arrayOfThisRow.push($(this).text()); });
        myTableArray.push(arrayOfThisRow);
    }
});
```

So 'myTableArray' will gives me the id, name, code.

```
1,sam,z123
2,kim,z234
```

Here is my MySql Table.

```
---------------------
id  | name    | code
---------------------
3   | sample1 | kkk
4   | sample2 | iii
---------------------
```

i am getting values in jquery through .text(). How do i insert these values into my DB.
Thanks.

Comment: Have you some PHP code yet ?

Comment: You have to use Ajax for that

Comment: check.. [jQuery `$ajax`](http://api.jquery.com/jquery.ajax/) OR [jQuery `$post`](http://api.jquery.com/jquery.post/)

Answer (score 0):

First of all, you need to send request via `Aajx`.

```
var request = $.ajax({
    url: "insert.php",              // Action file 
    type: "POST",                   // POST method
    data: { data : myTableArray },  // Your data
});
```

In `insert.php` you will get something like this:

```
$_POST["data"] = array(
    array(1, "sam", "z123"),
    array(2, "kim", "z234")
);
```

Mysql `insert` sytnax looks like:

```
INSERT INTO table (a,b,c) VALUES(1,2,3),(4,5,6),(7,8,9);
```

You need to loop through your data and fill your data into syntax above.

```
$values = array();
foreach($_POST["data"] as $insert){
    $values[] = "({$insert[0]}, '{$insert[1]}', '{$insert[2]}')";
}
```

`{$insert[0]}` is missing quotes, beacue is integer. You can use `NULL` instead if is `autoincrement`.

Your values are ready, now put them into `query`:

```
$query = "INSERT INTO table (id, name, code) VALUES".implode(',', $values).";";
```

*You are ready to execute query string!*

I preffer use prepared statements like following solution:

```
$values = array();
$data = array();
foreach($_POST["data"] as $insert){
    $values[] = "(?, ?, ?)";
    $data = array_merge($data, $insert);
}
```

Now `$data` contains all your data.